# Using PHP/SQL - How can I click an item in a list to display another list of items assoicated to the clicked item

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I refresh a detail select list when my master select changes using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914993/how-can-i-refresh-a-detail-select-list-when-my-master-select-changes-using-ajax)

I'm just working learning PHP again after some time away and after looking around think I need to use JS/ajax to make this happen which I intend to learn more about after I get more comforable with PHP. I would like to learn how to do this for some thing I am working on now.

I have a table of parent items which I display as a list of links. When a parent item is clicked I want the child items of the clicked parent to be displayed in another list. I can get the 2 lists to display with simple queries I just don't know how to get the page/sql query to update when clicked.

```
<?php require ('connection.inc.php'); ?>

<div id="lists">
    <h3>Lists</h3>
     <?php      
    $lists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lists") 
    or die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $lists )) 
    {  
    echo "<a href=\"#\">".$info['ListName']."</a><br />";
    } 
    ?>      
</div>  

<div id='listitems'>
    <h3>List <?php $parent=2; echo $parent?> Items</h3> 
     <?php
    $listitems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listitems WHERE parent=$parent") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $listitems )) 
    { 
    echo $info['itemName']."<br />";
    }   
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you've tagged the question with the answer: ajax

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Have a look at this question/answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914993/how-can-i-refresh-a-detail-select-list-when-my-master-select-changes-using-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Code issues aside (mysql_* == mucho deprecato), you need to check if the request is AJAX and output listitems.

I used jquery to simplify the ajax request.

```
<?php
require ('connection.inc.php');

/* AJAX request */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
        strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM listitems WHERE parent=%d',
            mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['parent']));
    $listitems = mysql_query($query)
            or die(mysql_error()); 
    printf('<h3>List %d Items</h3>', $_REQUEST['parent']);
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $listitems )) 
    { 
        echo $info['itemName']."<br />";
    }
    exit;
}

/* Normal request */
?>

<div id="lists">
    <h3>Lists</h3>
    <?php      
    $lists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lists") 
            or die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $lists )) 
    {  
        echo "<a href=\"#\">".$info['ListName']."</a><br />";
    } 
    ?>      
</div>  

<div id='listitems'>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($)){
     $('#lists').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
         $('#listitems').load(window.location.pathname, {parent: $(this).text()});
         return false;
     });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I click a list link no items load. Any clue what might be causing this? I thought it might be something to do with parent id's but after changing them around I still couldn't get the list of items to show. The page source shows the listitems area as empty.

Comment: Got it working with some help. I posted the complete answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5914993/1853914 because this got shut down after being labeled a duplicate.